# Stopping a repeating scheduled message

Tags: akka.net

We want an actor to stop itself after a period of some inactivity (i.e. after it hasnt received a certain kind of message for x minutes).  I don't see any built-in support for this, so I've opted to use the scheduler.

The actor itself sets a scheduled message from itself to itself, as follows:

```
Context
    .System
    .Scheduler
    .ScheduleTellRepeatedly(_expiryInterval, _expiryInterval, Self, new ExpiryCheckMessage(), Self);
```

On receiving this message:

```
Receive<ExpiryCheckMessage>(x => {
    if(IsExpired())
    {
        Context.Stop(Self);
    }
});
```

But after expiring and stopping the actor the scheduled messages keep sending resulting in deadletters.

What is the best way to stop a scheduled message in this case?

Comment: There's an extension method named [ScheduleTellRepeatedlyCancelable](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/9B66375D.htm), which return a cancellation object that can be used to stop the repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB: I'm familiar with Akka on the JVM, not on .Net.

[From the Akka docs for ScheduleTellRepeatedly](http://api.getakka.net/docs/stable/html/3E6D3122.htm) it appears that there's an optional `cancelable` parameter of type `ICancelable`.  So I would imagine that something like (this is literally the first C# I've ever attempted to write, so apologies in advance):

```
// Somewhere in the actor's scope
var cancellationKey = new Cancelable(Context.System.Scheduler);

Context
    .System
    .Scheduler
    .ScheduleTellRepeatedly(
        _expiryInterval,
        _expiryInterval, 
        Self,
        new ExpiryCheckMessage(),
        Self, 
        cancellationKey
    );

Receive<ExpiryCheckMessage>(x =>
    if (IsExpired()) {
        cancellationKey.Cancel();
        Context.Stop(Self);
    }
}
```